# Distance and midpoint - which belongs to Point and which belongs to Line?

Tags: java, oop, computer-science

From an Object Oriented Programming perspective, given two classes: Line (two Points) and Point (two floats). Which should hold the function `distance()` and which should hold `midpoint()`?

My initial thought was that `midpoint()` should belong to Line, and `distance()` to Point, because the Point should know the distance between itself and another point. Whereas `midpoint()` is more of a third-person calculation, that reviews two Points.

But then, when I thought about it, I realized that a Point knows its X and Y coordinates. So both functions should belong to Point. This would also save the creation of `getX()` and `getY()` getters. Line can call these functions for its own Points.

Or maybe Line should hold both functions?

So which is right? Or.. Is there another option?

Comment: I always put `distance` into `Point`, ***but*** rather then 0,0 instead of another point. Some example^ `len = (new SubstractedPoint(pointA, pointB)).distance()`. Obviously, it's not performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the distance function & midpoint function in Line class !
Because both function required two points .
Below I am giving the code example that class point has two floating variable named as 'x' & 'y' , getx & gety functions .The other class Line has aggregate with point class & having two object p1 & p2 which is used to calculate the distance between two points & midpoint .

```
class point
{

    float x, y;

public:
    float getx()
    {
        return x;
    }

    float gety()
    {
        return y;
    }

    void setx(float _x)
    {
        x=_x;
    }

    void sety(float _y)
    {
        y=_y;
    }
};

class line
{

    point p1, p2;

public:

    void distance()
    {
        cout << "Distance : " << sqrt(pow((p2.getx() - p1.getx()), 2) + pow((p2.gety() - p1.getx()), 2));
    }

    void midpoint()
    {
        cout << "Mid point : (" << ((p1.getx() + p2.getx()) / 2) << " , " << ((p1.gety() + p2.gety()) / 2) << " )";
    }
};

void main()
{
    // calling object
}
```